# Concatenate string in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, concatenation

I am working on an HTML page and I want to concatenate a URL for an image.
For example, if I want the image with the name 5:

```
"testimage.com/5.png"
```

However, the image id is a variable, test.image_id.
Using Java instincts, I wanted to do something like

```
"testimage.com/"+test.image_id+".png"
```

But obviously that does not work because it's HTML.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you working this on JSP or in JAVA file?

Comment: imageId is a variable of what?

Comment: HTML doesn't have variables

Comment: HTML doesn't have variables. Are you talking about JavaScript?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. jQuery and Javascript plugins are compiled at the bottom of the file; I am working with a sample HTML file from my instructor, and I know nothing about it.

Answer (score 1):

With only HTML you can't do it, use javascript instead:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="id_img"/>
<input type="button" value="get Image" onclick="getImg()"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function getImg(){
 var id_img=document.getElementById("id_img").value;
 var img="testimage.com/"+id_img+".png";
 alert(img);
}
// And manage it to do whatever you want.
```